# preg_match_all use

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that always follows the format:

```
This Fee Name :  *  Fee Id  * Fee Amount  $* is required for this activity
```

Example:

```
This Fee Name :  STATE TITLE FEE  Fee Id  2 Fee Amount  $5.50 is required for this activity
```

What I would like to do using PHP is pass the string and get the results

- `STATE TITLE FEE`
- `2`
- `5.50`

I'm pretty sure `preg_match_all` is what I want, but cannot figure out how to use the regex properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$a = 'This Fee Name :  STATE TITLE FEE  Fee Id  2 Fee Amount  $5.50 is required for this activity';
$regex = '/This Fee Name :  (.+)  Fee Id  (.+) Fee Amount  \$(.+) is required for this activity/';
$matches = array();
preg_match($regex, $a, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(91) "This Fee Name :  STATE TITLE FEE  Fee Id  2 Fee Amount  $5.50 is required for this activity"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "STATE TITLE FEE"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "5.50"
}
```

Comment: And is that a fee amount that will likely break whatever other part of the code processes fee amounts?

Comment: Oh, now I see where you were going with that question. Didn't think of making the regex validate the expression at the same time. Well observed.

Comment: Its best to used delimiters of information such as STATE TITLE FEE\t2\t5.50, then derive your string from your data.  You should never derive your data from a string, its just a backwards way of doing things.

Comment: I would agree Styler, but I am bing fed this data, I have no control over what I'm receiving.

Comment: Thanks Jong Bor for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you can just use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and capture the parts you want with parentheses (note that `?:` inside of parentheses indicates that the parentheses are being used for grouping only (ie there may be a decimal point and one or more digits after the dollar amount or not)).  (Warning:  Untested, but this should work.)

```
$str="This Fee Name :  STATE TITLE FEE  Fee Id  2 Fee Amount  $5.50 is required for this activity";

if(preg_match('/^This Fee Name :\s+(.*)\s+Fee Id\s+(\d)\s+Fee Amount\s+(\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+is required for this activity$/',$str,$matches))
{
  $fee_name=$matches[1];
  $fee_id=$matches[2];
  $fee_amount=$matches[3];
}
else
{
  //No matches!  Do something...or not.  Whatever.
}
```

Comment: Listen to the voice of experience: *always* test your code before posting it here. :/  And with tools like Ideone available, there's no excuse *not* to test--check it out: **[demo](http://ideone.com/qNeL3)**.   (Your code is missing a parenthesis, by the way.)

Answer (score 0):

In the PHP.net docs you will see `preg_match_all` is used by calling the function with the specified arguments:

> int preg_match_all ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = PREG_PATTERN_ORDER [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )

The first argument, the pattern, is how you capture the information from the next argument, the subject.

The subject is the text you wish you match.  It will be your string of information that you specified... 'This Fee Name : ... etc'

The third argument is a new array in which you are going to store your results.

However there is a fundamental flaw in the way you would like to parse your string using regular expressions.  You have no common delimiters that separate your "values" from your "keys".

If I were you, in this situation, I would just use `explode()`.

Try this:

```
$string = "This Fee Name :  *  Fee Id  * Fee Amount  $* is required for this activity";
$name = explode("This Fee Name :", $string, 2);
$name = $name[1];

$id = explode("Fee Id", $string, 2);
$id = $id[1];

$amount = explode("\$", $string, 2);
$amount = explode(" ", $amount[1], 2);
$amount = $amount[0];

echo "$name";
echo "$id";
echo "$amount";
```

I haven't tested any of this and haven't used PHP in a few months but hey, give it a try!